optional named argument after variadic argument
In PHP 7.x, I had some function that get array of parameters and then some flags.
a simplified sample:
<?php
    function sum($param, $min=0, $max=100)
    {
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($param as $value)
            if ($value>=$min && $value<=$max)
                $sum += $value;
        return $sum;
    }

    echo sum([100, 10, 4], 0, 50);
?>

Now in PHP 8.1, I want to change function definition to variadic (unpack array), and function call to named arguments
so I changed the function definition to this:
    function sum(...$param, $min=0, $max=100)

and function call to this:
    echo sum(100, 10, 4, max:50);

But I got this error message:
Fatal error: Only the last parameter can be variadic in test.php on line 2
Any idea to solve?
TIA

What about making it, well, last parameter?

$min and $max are less useful. But $param is the major parameter of this function. The most common use of this function is similar to: $s = sum(10, 20, 30, 40); .So I need the parameter $param as first parameter. Even if I have to convert it to an array like in PHP 7.x.

Actually what you need is irrelevant here as PHP clearly told you. You either drop it (and i.e. use array instead) or move your variadic argument to the end of argument list or it will simply not work otherwise.

Relevant (if not a suitable dupe target): PHP Fatal error: Cannot use positional argument after argument unpacking

You need to rewrite the order, so as the error says:

the variadic parameter as last argument.

function sum($min=0, $max=100, ...$param)


Make two functions. One with 3 arguments called sumMinMax() and one with 1 argument called sum().

$min and $max are less useful. But $param is the major parameter of this function. The most common use of this function is similar to: $s = sum(10, 20, 30, 40); .So I need the parameter $param as first parameter. Even if I have to convert it to an array like in PHP 7.x.

Thanks @makus-zeller, but I'm looking for a cleaner code.

function sum($param=[], $min=0, $max=100) is okay. Why will you call sum(10, 20, 30, 40); and not a computed array of any size?

If there is no better way, I will use this. Thanks.

I don't think so. Calling sum([10, 20, 30, 40]); does not make it more complicated. I would like to know some examples why you want a variadic version as first argument.

This was a simplified example. some of my functions are most complexed than this. like: function get_resources(array $stations, ?string $owner=null, bool $is_alive=false, bool $is_paused=false, ?int $state=null, int $min_usage=0, ?int $max_usage=null, ?string $has_tag=null)

If a function has that many parameters, the software design failed.
